# How to get MethodInfo of interface method, having implementing MethodInfo of class method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, methodinfo

I have a `MethodInfo` of an *interface* method and `Type` of a *class* that implements the *interface*.
I want to find the `MethodInfo` of the class method that implements the interface method.

The simple `method.GetBaseDefinition()` does not work with interface methods.
Lookup by name won't work either, because when implementing interface method explicitly it can have any name (yes, not in C#).

So what is the *correct* way of doing that that covers all the possibilities?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

OK, I found a way, using [GetInterfaceMap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap.aspx).

```
var map = targetType.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceMethod.DeclaringType);
var index = Array.IndexOf(map.InterfaceMethods, interfaceMethod);

if (index == -1)
{
    //this should literally be impossible
}

return map.TargetMethods[index];
```

Comment: index return -1 when dealing with a generic method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method!

```
public static MethodInfo GetImplementedMethod(this Type targetType, MethodInfo interfaceMethod)
{
    if (targetType is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(targetType));
    if (interfaceMethod is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(interfaceMethod));

    var map = targetType.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceMethod.DeclaringType);
    var index = Array.IndexOf(map.InterfaceMethods, interfaceMethod);
    if (index < 0) return null;

    return map.TargetMethods[index];
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this.

```
var interfacemethodParameterTypes = interfaceMethodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();

var map = targetType.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceMethodInfo.DeclaringType);

return map.TargetType.GetMethod(interfaceMethodInfo.Name, interfacemethodParameterTypes);
```