# C# Reflection to get attribute attached to interface implementation method

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a type of `TestTopicNotificationHandler` and I wish to get the `MessageBusSubscription` attributes attached to the handle method of any ITopicNotificationHandler<> method that is implemented within the class.

There a couple of scenarios:

1. There may not be the attribute attached to each interface implementation, as in the case below with `Task Handle(OtherNotification notification)`
2. I want to avoid looking up via function name `Handle` as in this case it would pickup `Task Handle(bool notAnInterfaceImplementation)` which his not actually a signature of ITopicNotificationHandler
3. It should also ignore methods signatures which are valid (in terms of `ITopicNotificationHandler`), but not defined in the class interface list

How can i achieve the above please, to find the linked implementation and pull the attribute from it (without reflecting by method name) similar to below:

```
var type = typeof(TestTopicNotificationHandler);
var attributes = FindAttributes(type);
// above function call returns the attributes that are defined in the class
// { [MessageBusSubscription("v1\test", QualityOfService.AtMostOnce)], [MessageBusSubscription("v1\yes", QualityOfService.AtMostOnce)]
```

Where this would be a typical class implementation:

```
class TestTopicNotificationHandler : ITopicNotificationHandler<TestTopicNotification>, ITopicNotificationHandler<YesNotification>, ITopicNotificationHandler<OtherNotification>
{
    [MessageBusSubscription("v1\test", QualityOfService.AtMostOnce)]
    public Task Handle(TestTopicNotification notification)
    {
    return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
    [MessageBusSubscription("v1\yes", QualityOfService.AtMostOnce)]
    public Task Handle(YesNotification notification)
    {
    return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
    // this should be ignored as whilst listed, it does not have an attribute attached
    public Task Handle(OtherNotification notification)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // this should be ignored as whilst valid interface signature, it is not listed in the implementation list of the class
    public Task Handle(NonListedNotification notification)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }   
    
    // this should be ignored it is not an interface
    [MessageBusSubscription("invalid", QualityOfService.AtMostOnce)]
    public Task Handle(bool notAnInterfaceImplementation)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find if a method is implementing specific interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379276/how-to-find-if-a-method-is-implementing-specific-interface/7379485) Or perhaps [Translating a MethodInfo object obtained from an interface type, to the corresponding MethodInfo object on an implementing type in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525096/translating-a-methodinfo-object-obtained-from-an-interface-type-to-the-correspo/1525249).

Comment: Could you please provide the interface as well and a list of methods you **do** want to return?

Comment: You can call `typeof(TestTopicNotificationHandler ).GetMethods()` on your type, filtering on 'Handle' then check the attributes on each of those methods until you find the ones you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetInterfaceMap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfacemap?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_GetInterfaceMap_System_Type_) to do something like this:

```
var type = typeof(TestTopicNotificationHandler);
foreach (var implementedInterface in type.GetInterfaces())
{
    if (!implementedInterface.IsGenericType
        || implementedInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(ITopicNotificationHandler<>))
        continue;
    
    var interfaceMap = type.GetInterfaceMap(implementedInterface);  
    foreach (var implementedMethod in interfaceMap.TargetMethods)
    {
        var attribute = implementedMethod.GetCustomAttribute<MessageBusSubscriptionAttribute>();
        if (attribute == null)
            continue;
        
        Console.WriteLine($"{implementedMethod.Name}: {attribute.Path}");
    }
}
```

We find all of the `ITopicNotificationHandler` interfaces that the type implements. For each one, we get a mapping which maps the methods defined on the interface to the corresponding methods defined on the type. We loop through each of the corresponding methods defined on the type, and look at the attributes for each.

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zgfVVq)

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. Since we can only ever have one implementation of a specific interface handler, woudl w2e therefore only have one member of the enumerable returned by `interfaceMap.TargetMethods`?

Comment: `TargetMethods` will contain one element per method in that interface which is implemented in that type. So if the interface defined 2 methods (and your type implemented both of them), then `TargetMethods` would have 2 elements

Comment: Makes perfect sense, code perfect, everything 100% clear. In this case i can throw if more than one since it should only ever contain `Handle` method

Answer (score 0):

*I want to avoid looking up via function name* - Why is this a requirement?

Anyway, here is a solution that finds all methods called `Handle`, that have the MessageBusSubscription attribute:

```
var allMethods = typeof(TestTopicNotificationHandler).GetMethods();
var handleMethods = allMethods.Where(x=>x.Name=="Handle");
foreach(var method in handleMethods)
{
    var attr = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MessageBusSubscription));
    if(attr.Any())
    {
       // Here you have the method with the attribute. 
    }
}
```

It should be pretty easy to adapt this to also look up the methods defined in the interface and ignore them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uSvfre. See how it prints "Handle(System.Boolean)", when the comments say that method shouldn't be printed