# GetMethod overload returns null

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I want to get a method from specific interface, but it can be in multiple interfaces. I write this code:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, T, int>> CreateCompareTo<TProperty>(MemberExpression expression, Expression<Func<T, T, int>> result) where TProperty : IComparable<TProperty>, IComparable
{
    var methodInfo = typeof(TProperty).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(IComparable<TProperty>), typeof(IComparable) });
    ...
```

MSDN

> An array of Type objects representing the number, order, and type of
>   the parameters for the method to get.

So I expect that it will search method through `IComparable<T>`, and, if didn't found, will search it in non-generic `IComparable`. But it doesn't. Well, now I rewrite it:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, T, int>> CreateCompareTo<TProperty>(MemberExpression expression, Expression<Func<T, T, int>> result) where TProperty : IComparable<TProperty>, IComparable
{
    Type t = typeof(TProperty);
    var methodInfo = t.GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(IComparable<TProperty>) }) ?? t.GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(IComparable) });
    ...
```

And now it works.

Why first option is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(IComparable<TProperty>), typeof(IComparable)})`
>
> So I expect that it will search method through IComparable, and, if didn't found, will search it in non-generic IComparable

No, it looks for a method with the signature `CompareTo(IComparable<TProperty>, IComparable)`.

This is also in the [`Type.GetMethod()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Searches for the specified public method **whose parameters match the specified argument types**.

Comment: Okay, thanks for reply. But then, what method can satisfy my needs? This way looks ugly

Comment: Not sure what your needs are. See [How to get MethodInfo of interface method, having implementing MethodInfo of class method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113635/how-to-get-methodinfo-of-interface-method-having-implementing-methodinfo-of-cla).

Comment: I want to get a method from non-generic interface only if it doesn't exist in generic. The only way I found is just call GetMethod twice, but it's ugly beacause of copy-paste and performance reasons.