# How detect is a method in a C# class is implementing a method from an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to be able to use reflection to tell that an implementation of the method `GetName` in `SomClassImpl` comes from the interface `IHasName`. As an example:

```cs
public interface IHasName
{
    string GetName();
}

public interface IOtherInterface
{
    //...elided...
}

public class MyClass : IHasName, IOtherInterface
{
    /*
     * I want to use reflection to know this 
     * implements IHasName.GetName()
     */
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "me";
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

When I tried `typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("GetName").GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType` and `typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("GetName").DeclaringType`, they both return the implementing class, **not** the interface.

Comment: Unless `MyClass` is abstract, isn't it *required* to implement `GetName`? When would there be a case that it isn't implemented but still implements the interface? I understand that new C# versions have interface implementations, but I think this is syntactic sugar for inserting the implementation into the derived class...

Comment: @RonBeyer I think I was unclear, sorry. I don't need to know it implemented interface "X". I want to know instead, "this method is from interface X, and this one is from interface Y, and this one is from the impending class only"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113635/how-to-get-methodinfo-of-interface-method-having-implementing-methodinfo-of-cla is probably what you are looking for... Note that same method can be implementing multiple interfaces and be careful with multiple methods with the same name

Comment: `var iFC = myClass.GetType().GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(ifc => ifc.GetMethods().Any(m => m.Name.Equals("[MethodName]")));`. Or with a value found with `myClass.GetType().GetMethods()`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The link you posted is exactly the code I tried that did *not* work

Comment: @DonRhummy you may want to [edit] post to explain how/why GetInterfaceMap did not work...

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities your scenario to happen:

1. Class implements the interface
2. Class inherits a class which implements the interface

In the former case, `typeof(Foo).GetMethod("GetName", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindiFoongFlags.DeclaredOnly)` returns the method info.

In the latter case, `typeof(Bar).GetMethod("GetName", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)` returns `null`.

See [an example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2nDIC1).

Answer (score 1):

The following will tell if the object implements the interface:

```
unkObj is IHasName
```

This will too if using reflection on a type instead of an object:

```
typeof(IHasName).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyClass))
```

This will get the method associated with the interface, and invoking it with any type that implements the interface with call the associated method in its class:

```
MethodInfo methodIHasName = typeof(IHasName).GetMethod("GetName", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
string name = methodIHasName.Invoke(unkObj, new object[0]);
```

If you absolutely need to get the `MethodInfo` of `MyClass` and all you have is the `MethodInfo` of the interface `IHasName`, you can map the interface as follows: [(Thanks @Alexei Levenkov for the link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048346/how-detect-is-a-method-in-a-c-sharp-class-is-implementing-a-method-from-an-inter/56048599#comment98738715_56048346)

```
var map = typeof(MyClass).GetInterfaceMap(methodIHasName.DeclaringType);
var index = Array.IndexOf(map.InterfaceMethods, methodIHasName);
return map.TargetMethods[index];
```

Comment: this is the right answer as the other one assumes that interface methods are implemented with the same name, but does not take into account explicit implementation.